# Google Adsense responsive ad units are causing blank spaces sometimes in mobile view

Tags: responsive-design, adsense

I am using the Adsense recommended responsive ad unit for my responsive website leaderboard Ad. The data-ad-format for the unit is set to rectangle, horizontal.

For desktop views the ad shows well with a leaderboard always. But for mobile view the ads sometimes show 320×100 filling the space well but other times it shows smaller sized mobile ad units leaving a blank space below them because instead of resizing it's container div and iframe to less than 100px, Adsense sets the height to be 100px.

My own container div for the ad unit does not have any height set so that it resizes to accommodate any size ad. See the screenshots below. I do not want to see the blank space below the ad and want Adsense unit to set its own height to less than 100px whatever it may be when a smaller ad is shown from the inventory.

*See the space below the smaller mobile ad shown sometimes by Adsense. This is not caused by my container div (it has no specified height, i have also tried height:auto) but by Adsense setting its ad unit height to 100px even though the ad is of smaller height.*
[image: space below the smaller ad. Not caused by my container div but by Adsense setting it's own height to 100px even though the ad is smaller height.]

*A normal 100px height ad unit filling showing correctly without any extra height*
[image: A normal 100px height ad unit filling showing correctly without any extra height]

Answer (score -1):

As I know, leader board ad unit is not a responsive ad unit; it is fixed as 728x90 pixels.

Leader board ad unit performs better on Desktop view.

But Google is very smart serves small size ad units on mobile within the existing ad units sometimes or sometimes its shows blank.

***What I would recommend please choose while creating an ad unit from ad sizes -> showing -> “Responsive”***

There will be two responsive ad units, use first one then Google will serve according to the screen size ads and they will perform better.

***All the best***